# How does similarity function in SpaCy works?

Tags: python, machine-learning, spacy, text-analytics-api

I have tried one e.g,

'Positive' and 'Negative' they are not similar words instead they are opposite but still spaCy gives me 81% similarity ratio for them.

here is my code,

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
word1 = nlp(u'negative')
word2 = nlp(u'positive') 
word1_word2 = word1.similarity(word2)

print(word1_word2)
```

Comment: If not SpaCy which library is good for text similarity in Python. ? I have tried gensim and sklearn but still they are not giving adequate results..

Answer (score 4):

Typically, word similarities like this are computed using cosine similarity between their corresponding word vectors. Words often used in the same contexts end up in similar locations in the vector space, on the assumption that words that get used similarly mean similar things. E.g., King and Queen might be similar, and King and Man might be similar, but Queen and Man should be a bit less similar (though they still both refer to "people", and they're both nouns, so they'll probably still be more similar than, say, Man and Combusted).

You want these words ('Positive' and 'Negative') to be negatives of each other (cosine similarity of -1), but they're similar because they're almost exactly the same word besides one being the negation of the other. The global semantic vector space incorporates many more ideas than just negation, and so these two words end up being very similar in other ways. What you can do is compute their average vector, then `Positive -> average = - (Negative -> average)`, and that difference vector `Positive -> average` (or, more precisely, `"Positive" - ("Positive" - "Negative") / 2`) would approximate the idea of negation that you're particularly interested in. That is, you could then add that vector to other cases to negate them too, e.g. `"Yes" + ("Negative" - "Positive") ~= "No"`

All that just to say, the effect you're observing is not a fault of Spacy, and you won't avoid it by using Gensim or Sklearn, it's due the nature of what "similarity" means in this context. If you want more comprehensible, human-designed semantic relationships between words, consider looking at WordNet, which is manually created and would be more likely to explicitly have some "negation" relation between your two words.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, this is really helpful. :-)